# How to make WordPress secure file download system

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin which backup wordpress database and lets user to download the backup file without saving it on server. I have trying to do that (force download) via ajax. So I have done like below,

```
function downloadURL(url) {
                var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
                    iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
                if (iframe === null) {
                    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                    iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
                    iframe.style.display = 'none';
                    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                }
                iframe.src = url;
            }

   var url_encode=encodeURIComponent('<?php echo plugins_url()."/link-to-process.php?save_to_disk=true"; ?>');
downloadURL(decodeURIComponent(url_encode));
```

This code access the process.php file directly for force download. In process.php there are containing some wordpress code.

My process.php code

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['save_to_disk'])) {
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=".$file);
header("Content-type: application/txt");

require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

$pre=$wpdb->prefix;
$arr=array($pre.'users',$pre.'usermeta',$pre.'terms',$pre.'term_taxonomy',$pre.'term_relationships',
    $pre.'posts',$pre.'postmeta',$pre.'options',
    $pre.'options',$pre.'links',$pre.'comments',$pre.'commentmeta' );

$imp=implode(",", $arr);
$exp=explode(",",$imp);
$mybackup = backup_tables(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME,$exp);
echo $mybackup;
}
```

So, my technique is there is a jQuery file which access a php file which process and let user to download the file.

But my problem is: anyone can do that without the jQuery file (if this plugin is installed). Like, if anyone enter this url in the browser

```
localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/plugins-name/process-file-name.php?save_to_disk=true
```

then a backup file will download. So this is a dangerous security problem.
Because anyone can download wordpress database information's by hitting this url.

So what should I do now? Is there any way to download the file in a safe way?

NOTE THAT : if I prevent direct access force download via jQuery, then force download does not work, and I want only download (not keep it on server).

Comment: My suggestion would be to research how AJAX works in WordPress and the correct way to utilise it. Regarding your question just check the current user and make sure they are logged in as an admin.

Comment: This question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this kind of stuff in wordpress would be to use nonce fields to check for refferer. Nonce fields are unique fields that are used by wordpress to check the integrity of a request. So every time someone goes to a form this field will be automatically populated as a hidden field and its value will change everytime. When this request goes to the processing file, wordpress has some functions that check if the nonce is valid or not.

Nonce can also be used with ajax, checkout these tutorials
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer
http://manofhustle.com/2013/06/18/how-to-add-a-wordpress-ajax-nonce/